# Inline SVG element too small in side navbar

Tags: html, css, svg

Hello all I have an SVG exported from Adobe Illustrator made for me that I am trying to use in a custom pull-out side navbar. For some reason the image will not resize based on any values. It displays properly when opening the SVG itself in a web browser, but it show up too tiny to even make out when in the navbar. Can someone please help me in utilizing the SVG on my site. I am currently using a Font Awesome icon as a placeholder as I was waiting for the logo to be finished up until today. I would like it to function similarly to that. The  list item of class 'logo' contains the placeholder that needs to be swapped with the actual logo. I can use the SVG in the body of the site.

Navbar in index.html

```
<nav class="custom-navbar">
    <ul class="custom-navbar-nav">

      <li class="logo">
        <a class="custom-nav-link">
          <span class="link-text">Kortney Stinson</span>
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="kickstarter-k"
            class="svg-inline--fa fa-kickstarter-k fa-w-12" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 384 512">
            <path fill="currentColor"
              d="M147.3 114.4c0-56.2-32.5-82.4-73.4-82.4C26.2 32 0 68.2 0 113.4v283c0 47.3 25.3 83.4 74.9 83.4 39.8 0 72.4-25.6 72.4-83.4v-76.5l112.1 138.3c22.7 27.2 72.1 30.7 103.2 0 27-27.6 27.3-67.4 7.4-92.2l-90.8-114.8 74.9-107.4c17.4-24.7 17.5-63.1-10.4-89.8-30.3-29-82.4-31.6-113.6 12.8L147.3 185v-70.6z"
              class="fa-primary"></path>
          </svg>


        </a>


      </li>


      <li class="custom-nav-item">
        <a href="#home" class="custom-nav-link">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="home"
            class="svg-inline--fa fa-home fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
            <path fill="currentColor"
              d="M280.37 148.26L96 300.11V464a16 16 0 0 0 16 16l112.06-.29a16 16 0 0 0 15.92-16V368a16 16 0 0 1 16-16h64a16 16 0 0 1 16 16v95.64a16 16 0 0 0 16 16.05L464 480a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V300L295.67 148.26a12.19 12.19 0 0 0-15.3 0zM571.6 251.47L488 182.56V44.05a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-56a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v72.61L318.47 43a48 48 0 0 0-61 0L4.34 251.47a12 12 0 0 0-1.6 16.9l25.5 31A12 12 0 0 0 45.15 301l235.22-193.74a12.19 12.19 0 0 1 15.3 0L530.9 301a12 12 0 0 0 16.9-1.6l25.5-31a12 12 0 0 0-1.7-16.93z"
              class="fa-primary"></path>
          </svg>
          <span class="link-text">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>


      <li class="custom-nav-item">
        <a href="#about" class="custom-nav-link">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="address-card"
            class="svg-inline--fa fa-address-card fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 576 512">
            <path fill="currentColor"
              d="M528 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h480c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-352 96c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64s-28.7 64-64 64-64-28.7-64-64 28.7-64 64-64zm112 236.8c0 10.6-10 19.2-22.4 19.2H86.4C74 384 64 375.4 64 364.8v-19.2c0-31.8 30.1-57.6 67.2-57.6h5c12.3 5.1 25.7 8 39.8 8s27.6-2.9 39.8-8h5c37.1 0 67.2 25.8 67.2 57.6v19.2zM512 312c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H360c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16zm0-64c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H360c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16zm0-64c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H360c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16z"
              class="fa-primary"></path>
          </svg>
          <span class="link-text">About</span>
        </a>
      </li>


      <li class="custom-nav-item">
        <a href="#work" class="custom-nav-link">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="laptop-code"
            class="svg-inline--fa fa-laptop-code fa-w-20" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 640 512">
            <path fill="currentColor"
              d="M255.03 261.65c6.25 6.25 16.38 6.25 22.63 0l11.31-11.31c6.25-6.25 6.25-16.38 0-22.63L253.25 192l35.71-35.72c6.25-6.25 6.25-16.38 0-22.63l-11.31-11.31c-6.25-6.25-16.38-6.25-22.63 0l-58.34 58.34c-6.25 6.25-6.25 16.38 0 22.63l58.35 58.34zm96.01-11.3l11.31 11.31c6.25 6.25 16.38 6.25 22.63 0l58.34-58.34c6.25-6.25 6.25-16.38 0-22.63l-58.34-58.34c-6.25-6.25-16.38-6.25-22.63 0l-11.31 11.31c-6.25 6.25-6.25 16.38 0 22.63L386.75 192l-35.71 35.72c-6.25 6.25-6.25 16.38 0 22.63zM624 416H381.54c-.74 19.81-14.71 32-32.74 32H288c-18.69 0-33.02-17.47-32.77-32H16c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v16c0 35.2 28.8 64 64 64h512c35.2 0 64-28.8 64-64v-16c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zM576 48c0-26.4-21.6-48-48-48H112C85.6 0 64 21.6 64 48v336h512V48zm-64 272H128V64h384v256z"
              class="fa-primary"></path>
          </svg>
          <span class="link-text">Work</span>
        </a>
      </li>



      <li class="custom-nav-item">
        <a href="#contact" class="custom-nav-link">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="paper-plane"
            class="svg-inline--fa fa-paper-plane fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path fill="currentColor"
              d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"
              class="fa-primary"></path>
          </svg>
          <span class="link-text">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>
```

Here is all of the CSS that is being applied to the Navbar

/* Side Navigation Bar */

```
.custom-navbar {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    transition: width 200ms ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

.custom-navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%
}

.custom-nav-item {
    width: 100%
}

.custom-nav-item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}

.custom-nav-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    color: var(--text-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.custom-nav-link:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
    background: var(--bg-secondary);
    color: var(--text-secondary);
}

.link-text {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.custom-nav-link svg {
    width: 2rem;
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
}




.fa-primary {
    color: #f9bc60;

}


.fa-primary,
.fa-secondary {
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.logo {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--text-secondary);
    background: var(--bg-secondary);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.3ch;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo svg {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.custom-navbar:hover .logo svg {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

This is the SVG I am trying to use.

```
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" width="1080px" height="1080px" viewBox="0 0 1080 1080"
        style="enable-background:new 0 0 1080 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
          .st0 {
            fill: #F9BC60;
          }
        </style>
        <g>
          <g>
            <polygon class="st0" points="470.04,589.59 456.54,589.59 497.02,490.41 510.52,490.41        " />
            <path class="st0" d="M608.83,490.41l-44.35,24.24v13.3v0.02v15.53l30.89,15.16l-30.89,15.28v15.65l44.35-24.24v-13.3v-0.02V536.5
            l-30.89-15.16l30.89-15.28V490.41z M607.51,564.56l-41.7,22.8v-12.6l30.16-14.92l2.4-1.19l-2.41-1.18l-30.16-14.8v-12.5
            l41.7,22.64L607.51,564.56L607.51,564.56z" />
            <path class="st0"
              d="M547.92,509.18v15.65l-30.89,15.28l30.89,15.16v15.55l-44.35-24.08v-13.31L547.92,509.18z" />
          </g>
          <path class="st0"
            d="M652.33,633.55H427.67v-187.1h224.65v187.1H652.33z M441.54,619.68h196.92V460.32H441.54V619.68z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this: remove the width and the height of the svg element and use this `viewBox="427.6 446 225 187"`. Since you intend to use the svg inside an html document you don't need to use the namespaces.

In order to know what viewBox to use I've added an id to the `<g>` element that is wrapping all the shapes inside. Then in the javascript I'm `console.log(elSVG.getBBox())` This is returning an SVGRect object with the following properties: x, y, width, height. Next I'm using those properties to define the new viewBox value like so: `viewBox="x y width height"`. Now the svg element will take all the available width, i.e the width of the parent element.

Also I've removed the style element since you can use the css instead

```css
.st0 {
            fill: #F9BC60;
          }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="427.6 446 225 187">
        <g id="elSVG">
          <g>
            <polygon class="st0" points="470.04,589.59 456.54,589.59 497.02,490.41 510.52,490.41        " />
            <path class="st0" d="M608.83,490.41l-44.35,24.24v13.3v0.02v15.53l30.89,15.16l-30.89,15.28v15.65l44.35-24.24v-13.3v-0.02V536.5
            l-30.89-15.16l30.89-15.28V490.41z M607.51,564.56l-41.7,22.8v-12.6l30.16-14.92l2.4-1.19l-2.41-1.18l-30.16-14.8v-12.5
            l41.7,22.64L607.51,564.56L607.51,564.56z" />
            <path class="st0"
              d="M547.92,509.18v15.65l-30.89,15.28l30.89,15.16v15.55l-44.35-24.08v-13.31L547.92,509.18z" />
          </g>
          <path class="st0"
            d="M652.33,633.55H427.67v-187.1h224.65v187.1H652.33z M441.54,619.68h196.92V460.32H441.54V619.68z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
```

UPDATE

The OP is commenting;

> I wanted to ask, would I simply edit the width/height to enlarge or decrease the size of the SVG if it was used somewhere else where more fine-tuned control was required? Or would I need to edit any other values?

The svg element will take all the available width, i.e the width of the parent element.

Alternatively you can add a width in CSS. Avoid using both width and height or at least keep the same aspect ratio.

If you need to use the same icon several times you can create a new svg element with the same viewBox and instead of repeating the code you can reuse what in my code is the `<g id="elSVG">`

```css
.st0 {fill: #F9BC60;}

svg:nth-of-type(1){width:50px}
svg:nth-of-type(2){width:150px}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="427.6 446 225 187">
        <g id="elSVG">
          <g>
            <polygon class="st0" points="470.04,589.59 456.54,589.59 497.02,490.41 510.52,490.41        " />
            <path class="st0" d="M608.83,490.41l-44.35,24.24v13.3v0.02v15.53l30.89,15.16l-30.89,15.28v15.65l44.35-24.24v-13.3v-0.02V536.5
            l-30.89-15.16l30.89-15.28V490.41z M607.51,564.56l-41.7,22.8v-12.6l30.16-14.92l2.4-1.19l-2.41-1.18l-30.16-14.8v-12.5
            l41.7,22.64L607.51,564.56L607.51,564.56z" />
            <path class="st0"
              d="M547.92,509.18v15.65l-30.89,15.28l30.89,15.16v15.55l-44.35-24.08v-13.31L547.92,509.18z" />
          </g>
          <path class="st0"
            d="M652.33,633.55H427.67v-187.1h224.65v187.1H652.33z M441.54,619.68h196.92V460.32H441.54V619.68z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
      
 <svg viewBox="427.6 446 225 187">
 <use xlink:href="#elSVG" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer and marked as the solution, but I wanted to ask, would I simply edit the width/height to enlarge or decrease the size of the SVG if it was used somewhere else where more fine-tuned control was required? Or would I need to edit any other values?

Comment: I've updated my answer and added some explanation. Please take a look.